# Find a sequence of numbers such that random variable converges

Tags: probability-theory

**The problem**

There are independant random variables $\xi_1, \xi_2, ...$ with the same distribution $U_{0,4}$

Let us $S_n = \xi_1 + ... + \xi_n$

Find a sequence of $c_n$ such that $P(S_n < c_n) \rightarrow 0.4$

**My Attempt**

$\begin{array}{l}
P\left(S_{n}<c_{k}\right)=1-P\left(S_{n} \geq c_{k}\right) \\
P\left(S_{n} \geq c_{n}\right)=P\left(\frac{S_n}{n} \geq \frac{c_{k}}{n}\right) \leq {\text{Markov inequality}} \leq \frac{E S_{n}}{c_{k}}=\frac{n \mathbb{E}_{1}}{c_{k}} \rightarrow 0.6
\end{array}$

Find a $c_n$:

$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{4n}{2 c_n}=0.6 \Rightarrow c_{n}=\frac{4n}{1.2}$

$P\left(s_{n}<c_{k}\right)=1-P\left(S_{n} \geq C_{k}\right) \rightarrow 1 - 0.6 = 0.4$

**What do I need**

I am not sure about correctness of my solution. I would like to see my mistakes and figure out how to solve this problem correctly.

Comment: Does this show $\lim P(S_n < c_n) = 0.4$ or $\lim P(S_n < c_n) \ge 0.4$?

Comment: First of all, you have mixed up a lot of symbols. Your $c_n$ changes to $c_k,$ you have $S_n$ and $s_n$ and $C_k$ and that makes it all very confusing. 
Secondly, as pointed out already in the previous comment if you use Markov's inequality you only get that $\limsup P(S_n>c_n)\le 0.6.$ In fact, the limit is not even guaranteed. Finally, you $c_n>3n$ and it is easy to check that $P(S_n<3n)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$ by Law of large number.

Answer (score 1):

Using CLT, we know that $$P\left(\frac{S_n-2n}{\sqrt{n}}< x\right)\to P(Z< x),$$
as $n\to \infty,$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. It is a matter of re-writing the above expression to obtain
$$P(S_n<2n+x\sqrt{n})\to P(Z<x).$$

This solves your problem. Choose $x_{0.4}$ such that $P(Z<x_{0.4})=0.4$ and then $c_n=2n+x_{0.4}\sqrt{n}$ works. More generally, for any $r\in (0, 1)$ you can find $x_r$ such that $P(Z<x_r)=r$ and it would give you that
$P(S_n<c_n^r)\to r,$ where $c_n^r:=2n+x_r\sqrt{n}.$